# Nginx Rewrite Rule To 301 redirect filename.asp to filename.php

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have changed my file names from filename.asp to filename.php but now I want to 301 redirect all the requests coming to filename.asp to its equivalent filename.php

I have tried these variations but they only redirect to the homepage:

```
if ($request_uri ~ .*.asp.*) {

     rewrite ^ http://$host? permanent; 
     #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1.php permanent;
}
```

domain.com/folder/filename.asp 301 redirect to domain.com/folder/filename.php

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `if` to get just the `.asp` files, it can be handled purely in the rewrite:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)\.asp$ http://example.com/$1.php permanent;
```